# Failure to build with docker-compose: Invalid signal: SIGQUIT

Tags: docker, docker-compose

```
PS D:\>docker-compose up
Building app
Step 1/7 : FROM php:7.4-fpm-alpine
—> 5ae58b49885c
Step 2/7 : RUN apk add --no-cache autoconf curl dpkg-dev dpkg freetype-dev file g++ gcc giticu-dev jpeg-dev libc-dev libmcrypt-dev libpng-dev libjpeg-turbo-dev libxml2-dev libzip-dev make mariadb-dev postgresql-dev pkgconf php7-dev re2c rsync unzip wget zlib-dev
ERROR: Service ‘app’ failed to build: Invalid signal: SIGQUIT
```

Running:

```
docker run -ti 5ae58b49885c apk add --no-cache autoconf curl dpkg-dev dpkg freetype-dev file g++ gcc git icu-dev jpeg-dev libc-dev libmcrypt-dev libpng-dev libjpeg-turbo-dev libxml2-dev libzip-dev make mariadb-dev postgresql-dev pkgconf php7-dev re2c rsync unzip wget zlib-dev
```

seems to work except for the error at the end:

```
[...]
OK: 392 MiB in 105 packages
time="2020-05-23T11:54:06+05:00" level=error msg="Error waiting for container: failed to
shutdown container: container 4e49e4bb8234f213ed580978bc3a4f4cacff549f91affcf82783a2703f341ddb
encountered an error during hcsshim::System::waitBackground: failure in a Windows system
call: The virtual machine or container with the specified identifier is not running.
(0xc0370110): subsequent terminate failed container 4e49e4bb8234f213ed580978bc3a4f4cacff549f91affcf82783a2703f341ddb
encountered an error during hcsshim::System::waitBackground: failure in a Windows system
call: The virtual machine or container with the specified identifier is not running. (0xc0370110)"
```

Version: 19.03.8
OS/Arch: windows/amd64
Experimental: true

Switching containers doesn’t help. What can I do or how to debug?
Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Latest edge release 2.3.1.0 fixed this and many others problems